# Java shelling out to FFMPEG not running nor giving error

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm writing a Podcast downloader where I want to be able to download one or more podcasts then run them through FFMPEG.

It **does** run when I run the program in Windows.
It **does not** run when I run the program in Linux - Meaning FFMPEG may or may not have been called.  I have no way of knowing.  I get a -1 back from process.waitfor() but no error in my Java logs and no entries at all in the ffmpeg.log file.  And there is no file in the processed file directory that FFMPEG would have created.
It **does** run in Linux if I run the same command that fails in Java from the command line.

FFMPEG has the permissions: rwxr-xr-x , so it doesn't seem as if it'd be a permission error.  The Java code looks like:

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( commands );
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream( true );
    //  Added the next line to see if I could log an error from ffmpeg
    processBuilder.redirectOutput( ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo( new File( "./ffmpeg.log" ) ) );

    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    BufferedReader bufferedOutputReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( process.getInputStream() ) );
    do {
        outputString = bufferedOutputReader.readLine();
        if ( outputString != null ) {
            LOGGER.trace( outputString );
        }
    } while ( outputString != null );
    results = process.waitFor();
    LOGGER.debug( "Exit value: " + results );
```

The commands are:

```
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: /bin/ffmpeg 
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: -y 
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: -i 
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: "/home/todd/aggregator/incoming/Downrange Radio/Downrange_Radio_2023-02-15_The_Avidity_PD-10_Delivers_.mp3" 
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: -ac 
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: 1 
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: -af 
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: "atempo=1.4,volume=1.4" 
2023-10-25 16:21:52,452 224257 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG org.sperbolink.utils.CodecUtils - command string: "/home/todd/aggregator/processed/Downrange Radio/Downrange_Radio_2023-02-15_The_Avidity_PD-10_Delivers_.mp3"
```

And the manually constructed and run command line that DOES work is:

```
/bin/ffmpeg -y -i "/home/todd/aggregator/incoming/Downrange Radio/Downrange_Radio_2023-02-15_The_Avidity_PD-10_Delivers_.mp3" -ac 1 -af "atempo=1.4,volume=1.4" "/home/todd/aggregator/processed/Downrange Radio/Downrange_Radio_2023-02-15_The_Avidity_PD-10_Delivers_.mp3"
```

The ffmpeg.log file is empty, so I'm doubting whether FFMPEG is ever being reached.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I changed the commands to be

```
"/bin/ffmpeg 2> foo.txt"
```

and the execution code to:

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( commands );
//        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream( true );
    //  Added the next line to see if I could log an error from ffmpeg
//        processBuilder.redirectOutput( ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo( new File( "./ffmpeg.log" ) ) );
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        results = process.waitFor();
```

Running that command from the command line displays a list of MMPEG commands that can be run within foo.txt.  Upon running from within the Java app, the foo.txt file is empty, so it doesn't appear that FFMPEG ever gets reached.  But, I'm clueless why not.

**EDIT 2:**
I converted the /bin/ffmpeg path to uppercase to see if that would return an error and it did.

```
ERROR org.mrpc.utilities.ShellUtils - Cannot run program "/BIN/FFMPEG": error=2, No such file or directory
```

This seems to confirm that the Java Process object can locate ffmpeg successfully when it is properly cased (i.e. my original code) as I don't see an error message when the case is incorrect.  Still not sure why nothing happens when it is called.

Comment: "It does not run" is horribly imprecise.  What **does** it do, **exactly**?  Does it hang?  Does it throw any exception(s)?  Does it turn your computer into a pony that prances about the room?

Comment: I've updated the "doesn't run" section.

Comment: Don't redirect stderr. Inherit it and try again

Comment: g00se, I don't understand.  Could you show me what you mean?  Thx.